# Adding html entity to button text with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have button with some entity on it:

```
<button type='button' disabled class='buttonred' id="buttonred">&#10007;</button>
```

How can i change the button text to other entity?

```
document.getElementById('buttonred').text = '&#10004;';
```

Above will not work.

Comment: Instead of `text` you can use `innerHTML`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `innerHTML` instead of `text`, Hope this helps.

```js
document.getElementById('buttonred').innerHTML = '&#10004;';
```

```html
<button type='button' disabled class='buttonred' id="buttonred">&#10007;</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case to change from X in the button to a 'Tick' try using innerHTML.

```
document.getElementById('buttonred').innerHTML = '&#10004;';
```

fiddle for your reference http://jsfiddle.net/825sgc6x/